# iOS: jwPlayer launches video but only audio, no video

Tags: ios, swift, jwplayer

I have a view with a single button that executes this function:

```
func playVideo(withKey key: String) {
    let videoFile = key
    
    let baseUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let assetUrl = baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(videoFile)
    
    var playlist = [JWPlaylistItem]()
    let item = JWPlaylistItem()
    item.file = assetUrl.absoluteString
    playlist.append(item)
    
    
    let config = JWConfig()
    config.playlist = playlist
    config.controls = true
    config.autostart = true
    
    jwplyr = JWPlayerController(config: config)
    
    jwplyr?.delegate = self
    jwplyr?.fullscreen = true
}


func onFullscreen(_ event: JWEvent & JWFullscreenEvent) {
    if jwplyr!.fullscreen {
        print("OPEN")
    } else {
        jwplyr?.stop()
        jwplyr = nil
    }
    
}
```

The idea is for a video to play when the user taps on the button. Currently, the script executes, and I can hear the sound, but I can't see the video. The screen does not change. Other than the audio it's as if I didn't click the button.

I have verified that the file is there.

I am working with Swift 5 in XCode 12.4

Output window shows the following:

```
2021-03-24 15:06:35.395541-0500 myApp[20509:6532572] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2021-03-24 15:06:35.395701-0500 myApp[20509:6532572] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2021-03-24 15:06:35.703217-0500 myApp[20509:6532572] [] [15:06:35.703] 
    FigSubtitleSampleCreateFromPropertyList signalled err=50 (kFigCFBadPropertyListErr) (NULL or bad plist) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Prototypes/ClosedCaptions/FigCaptionCommand.c:792
2021-03-24 15:06:35.724089-0500 myApp[20509:6533458] [] [15:06:35.724] VMC2SetProperty signalled err=-12823 (kVMCParameterErr) (not a CFString) at /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/EmbeddedCoreMedia_Sim/EmbeddedCoreMedia-2765.6/Prototypes/MediaConverter/VideoMediaConverter2.c:7105
2021-03-24 15:06:35.756860-0500 myApp[20509:6532572] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7fa3feb2cb00>.
OPEN
```

Comment: which type of extension of your video ?

Comment: Video extension is mp4